# Iterate Array Of Points

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

I am needing to iterate an array of points, but I am getting a compile error of:

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'   WindowsFormsApplication1

This is my syntax, how should I re-write this so that I can iterate the array? (I am only showing one Point in the example, but in my real code there are about 20)

```
Point[] points = new Point[] { new Point { X = 50, Y = 40 } } };

for (int i=0;i<points[i].Count;i++) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(points[i].X);
    MessageBox.Show(points[i].Y);     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax for the second expression in the for loop is incorrect.  But really, a `foreach` makes more sense here:

```
Point[] points = new Point[] { new Point { X = 50, Y = 40 } } };

foreach(var point in points)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(point.X);
    MessageBox.Show(point.Y);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing an element (a single point) rather than the array itself. You want the count of all points in the array. So

Change

```
for (int i=0;i<points[i].Count;i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i<points.Length; i++)
```

or better yet, use the enumerator:

```
foreach (var point in points)
```